# Defining one side of a one to many relationship with PostgreSQL entity Framework

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I am, essentially, trying to define just one side of a one to many relationship using PostgreSQL entity framework and am producing the following error:

***System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'UserDao.TypeDao' of type 'TypeDao'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.***

So a little detail:

I am using asp.net core 3.1 using Razor Pages, Database is Postgres 12.2 and I am using Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 3.1.2

This is a conversion from an MVC project using EntityFramework 6.x using SQL Server

This is a large existing database so not using migrations but rather coding up the data access objects and context by hand.

I will talk about two data access classes **UserDao** and **TypeDao**

**TypeDao** is used throughout the database on hundreds of tables so what I want to achieve is that **UserDao** has one **TypeDao** and **TypeDao** "can be used in" many users. So I don't want a collection, in fact hundreds of collections, in the **TypeDao** object for **UserDao**, **ProductDao**, etc. etc.

So here are cut down versions of my **UserDao** and **TypeDao** data access objects:

```
[Table("user", Schema = "shared_kernal")]
public class UserDao
{
    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Column("type_id")]
    public Guid? TypeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TypeId")]
    public TypeDao Type { get; set; }
}

[Table("type", Schema = "shared_kernal")]
public class TypeDao
{
    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Column("creator_id")]
    public Guid CreatorId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CreatorId")]
    public UserDao Creator { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see there is a relationship defined in Type back to the User as the creator, as new types can be added, but there is no relationship intended to be the other side of the relationship defined in User to Type

This feels like the possible root of the error as it might well be confusing to ef to infer that I don't wan't the Creator relationship to be the other side of the Type relationship in User.

So... How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such relationships require [Manual configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#manual-configuration) - a `Has{One|Many}` followed by `With{One|Many}` pair. These are used to identify the relationship ends, multiplicity and the associated  navigation property (or no navigation property) of each end.

So the minimum needed to "unpair" `UserDao.Type` from `TypeDao.Creator` is

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserDao>()
    .HasOne(e => e.Type) // reference navigation property
    .WithMany(); // no collection navigation property
```

or

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TypeDao>()
    .HasOne(e => e.Creator) // reference navigation property
    .WithMany(); // no collection navigation property
```

For more info, see [Relationships - Manual Configuration - Single navigation property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#single-navigation-property-1) section of the EF Core documentation.

Comment: Many thanks Ivan. That was the correct solution, it worked perfectly. I've always just used annotations but can't figure out how to do it with annotations. Will spend a couple of hours with the EF docs and get some Fluent Api action going :) Would be interested if anyone does know an annotations only solution just out of interest to see if it can be dome.

Comment: You are welcome. And no, there is no data annotations solution. The only "pairing" annotation is `[InverseProperty]`, but it requires valid property name and does not accept `""` or `null` to indicate "no property".

Comment: Just a quick update to this. I've actually moved away from EF and now use Dapper, few extra lines of code but omg the control :) Not saying EF is bad, just a preference for micro ORM's that has evolved.